# Open-source software (alternative to Surfer) for contouring and 3D surface mapping

Tags: open-source, ubuntu, 3d, mapping

I am looking for an open-source software for contouring and 3D surface mapping, an *alternative to Surfer*. Presently, I am using Gnuplot, but I am looking for a simpler, user-friendly software for Ubuntu that produces publication-quality plots. I will be grateful if someone suggests for it! Thanks!